# Localizations.localeOf(context) is calling didChangeDependencies()

Tags: flutter, dart

i am using Localizations.localeOf(context) to get current locale of the app but using this it recalls the didChangeDependencies() and i need to stop recalling it because it reload the data in it.

```
 Text(Localizations.localeOf(context).languageCode == "hi" ? HindiTitle : EnglishTitle), // using this in build function
```

Answer (score 0):

It isn't caused by Localizations.locale()

In [didChangeDependencies - Flutter API](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/State/didChangeDependencies.html), there is a description:

> This method is also called immediately after initState.

Hope this is helpful.

Comment: Yes i am aware about this, but Localizations.localeOf(context) this use inherited widget and inherited widgets re-calls the didChangeDependencies 
please see https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/InheritedWidget-class.html then this https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/BuildContext/dependOnInheritedWidgetOfExactType.html

Comment: what codes in didChangeDependencies, maybe you could put them in initState...

Comment: didChangeDependencies usually only hold codes that only execute when dependencies change in my understanding...